# How created named volume with folder path in docker-compose

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I am in the process of configuring a multi-container setup for Wordpress using Docker (as per [this article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-with-docker-compose)).

At present, I have a `wordpress` service which has a named volume in it like so:

```
volumes:
  - wordpress:/var/www/html
```

Which works perfectly for the default Wordpress installation. But I also have some files that I need to pass into the container for the theme/plugins etc.

I understand that this would also be achievable by setting a mapping between the two paths on the server and the relevant container. Something like this:

```
volumes: 
  - ./wp-content:/var/www/html/wp-content
```

It's my understanding that a volume is named so that other containers can interact with it (as is required in my case, which you can see in the full `docker-compose.yaml` file below).

**So, what is the correct way to create a *named volume* which sets the paths so my files are mounted on the container?**

Here is the full `docker-compose.yaml` file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: db
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: .env
    volumes: 
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    command: '--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password'
    networks:
      - app-network

  wordpress:
    depends_on: 
      - db
    image: wordpress:5.1.1-fpm-alpine
    container_name: wordpress
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      - WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=db:3306
      - WORDPRESS_DB_USER=$MYSQL_USER
      - WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=$MYSQL_PASSWORD
      - WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=$MYSQL_DATABASE
    volumes:
      - wordpress:/var/www/html
    networks:
      - app-network

  webserver:
    depends_on:
      - wordpress
    image: nginx:1.15.12-alpine
    container_name: webserver
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - wordpress:/var/www/html
      - ./nginx-conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - certbot-etc:/etc/letsencrypt
    networks:
      - app-network

  phpmyadmin:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    env_file: .env
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
    networks:
      - app-network

  certbot:
    depends_on:
      - webserver
    image: certbot/certbot
    container_name: certbot
    env_file: .env
    volumes:
      - certbot-etc:/etc/letsencrypt
      - wordpress:/var/www/html
    command: certonly --webroot --webroot-path=/var/www/html --email ${LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL} --agree-tos --no-eff-email --staging -d ${DOMAIN} -d www.${DOMAIN}

volumes:
  certbot-etc:
  wordpress:
  dbdata:

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: could you please explain to me where is the problem, `wordpress:/var/www/html` ist set the path on your container to `/var/www/html`

Comment: Sure, firstly thanks for your time @LinSel

Comment: I'm looking to pull files I placed on the server (located in the user directory) to be mounted in the container. Just in the same way that this works `./wp-content:/var/www/html/wp-content `. But as the `wordpress` named version is used in multiple locations I'm not sure how to do this as I assume removing the name would cause the connection between containers to break

Comment: If it's not obvious I'm quite new to docker so this is a bit of a learning curve for me!

Answer (score 0):

you can copy files to your named Volume using the following:

```
docker cp /my/folder/myfile container:/var/www/html/myfile
```

replace `container` with your container name.

Comment: I'm looking to mount the volume so that it's a two-way connection. As WordPress has a `/wp-content/uploads` directory where CMS uploaded files are stored, these would be lost when the container is closed. So a simple copy doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: no data will be lost if you copied it to /var/www/html/myfile since it is a named volume , closing the container will not delete anything